# Why does ES6 generator functions are giving me different results on Angular 6 and chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Functioning of generators in Angular 6/7 is very confusing. My task is just to print a simple array from a generator function. I am successful by doing it in chrome developer tools as below.

```
function* foo() {
   yield 'a';
   yield 'b';
   yield 'c';
}

const values = [...foo()];
```

But the same thing, I am unable do it in Angular 6/7. I am getting a compilation error as

```
[ts] Type 'IterableIterator<"a" | "b" | "c">' is not an array type.
```

From the error, I can understand the issue. As the function foo() returns only one value a|b|c at each time we cannot use array operator on it.

But why is the same working on chrome developer tools? How can we make it work on Angular same as on chrome developer tools?

Comment: I don't know how angular works but maybe it only allows element spread on actual arrays? The ECMAScript spec certainly allows any iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856), it's a typescript problem.

To solve it you can use `--downlevelIteration` argument or instead of using the spread operator you can use `Array.from` function.

```
function* foo() {
    yield 'a';
    yield 'b';
    yield 'c';
}

const values = Array.from(foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, in browser's console you're writing JavaScript. Here, you get a TypeScript error. One solution would be to check the `downlevelIteration` option in the compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this go to your ***tsconfig.json*** and mention the ***target*** as ***es6***:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16022) for TypeScript: